# Query with M2M field

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following two models:

```
class Title(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class UpdateBatch(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    is_completed = models.BooleanField()
    titles = models.ManyToManyField(Title)
```

How would I get all titles in a batch that is not completed?

How would I get all titles in a batch that is completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all completed ones:

```
Title.objects.filter(updatebatch__is_completed=True)
```

Comment: Since it is boolean, `=True`, and `=False` would make it more explicit.